# css styling with bulma cards

Tags: html, css, angular, bulma, card

I do have the following HTML output:

[image]

so, as you can see the footer isn't matching...

my css component looks like this:

```
.card-equal-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-equal-height
.card-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**.card-equal-height.card-footer** this part is not working somehow. I want the footer to be matching the order cards, no matter how long the description is.

html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'card-highlight': product.listItemHovered}" class="card card-equal-height"
                 (mouseenter)="hoverListItem(product)"
                 (mouseleave)="hoverListItem(product)"
                 (click)="test(product)">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-square">
          <img [src]="product.imageURL" alt="{{product.title}}">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p class="title has-text-centered"> {{product.title}}</p>
        <p class="subtitle">{{product.price | currency: "USD"}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <button (click)="removeFromCart(product); showRemoved()"
                  class="button is-danger is-outlined is-pulled-left is-small"> Remove
          </button>
        </p>
        <p class="card-footer-item">
          <button (click)="addToCart(product);showAdded()"
                  class="button is-outlined is-primary is-pulled-right is-small"> Add to Cart
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve changing the height of "card-content" (forget change the .card-footer) using flex-grow

```
.card-equal-height
.card-content {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

For more about flex, check this [link in css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)